# Python not rendering on flask website hosted on pythonanywhere

Tags: python, html, flask, pythonanywhere

I'm trying to build a news aggregator site from RSS feeds. After successfully building it locally, I tried to host it on pythonanywhere.

My HTML appears to be working, but no content is being generated. It was working when it was on localhost but after switching to pythonanywhere it seems to have broken

What is currently looks like:[Site on PythonAnywhere](https://i.stack.imgur.com/o1twU.png)

Tried following the pythonanywhere flask tutorial, didn't get anywhere with it.

HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Totum News</title>
    <link rel="icon" href="{{ url_for('static', filename='logo2.png') }}" type="image/png">
    <style>
body {
    font-family: 'Verdana', sans-serif;
    background-color: #f4f4f4;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    text-align: center;
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    justify-content: center;
}

.header {
    text-align: center;
    background: #ED1941;
    color: white;
    width: 100%;
    height: 60px;
}

.logo {
    height: 100%;
    width: auto;
}

.article-box {
    border: 1px solid #ccc;
    margin: 10px;
    padding: 10px;
    max-width: 300px;
    background-color: #fff;
    box-shadow: 0 0 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
    transition: box-shadow 0.3s ease-in-out;
    flex: 0 0 calc(25% - 20px);
    box-sizing: border-box;
    overflow: hidden;
}

.article-box:hover {
    box-shadow: 0 0 15px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
}

.article-box img {
    max-width: 100%;
    height: auto;
    border-radius: 5px;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
}

.article-box .description {
    max-height: 3.6em;
    overflow: hidden;
    white-space: normal;
}

.article-box .description.short {
    white-space: nowrap;
    overflow: hidden;
    text-overflow: ellipsis;
}

strong {
    color: #333;
    font-size: 1.2em;
}

small {
    color: #777;
}

a {
    color: #007bff;
    text-decoration: none;
}

a:hover {
    text-decoration: underline;
}

/* Media query for smaller screens (max-width: 600px) */
@media only screen and (max-width: 600px) {
    .article-box {
        flex: 0 0 calc(50% - 20px); /* Two boxes per row */
    }
}
</style>
</head>

<body>
    <div class="header">
        <img class="logo" src="{{ url_for('static', filename='logo.png') }}" alt="Totum News Logo">
    </div>
    {% for article in articles %}
    <div class="article-box">
        {% if article.media_thumbnail %}
        <img src="{{ article.media_thumbnail[0]['url'] }}" alt="{{ article.title }}">
        {% endif %}
        <strong>{{ article.title }}</strong><br>
        <small>{{ article.published }}</small><br>
        
        {# Display article content without HTML tags #}
        {% set summary_without_tags = article.text|striptags %}
        <div class="description">{{ summary_without_tags[:104] }}{% if summary_without_tags|length > 104 %}...{% endif %}</div>
        
        <a href="{{ article.link }}" target="_blank">Read more</a>
    </div>
    {% endfor %}
    </body>
</html>
```

Python:

```
from flask import Flask, render_template
import feedparser
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests

app = Flask(__name__)

# Define RSS feed URLs
rss_feeds = [
    {'name': 'BBC News', 'url': 'http://feeds.bbci.co.uk/news/rss.xml'},
    {'name': 'The Guardian', 'url': 'https://www.theguardian.com/politics/rss'},
    {'name': 'The Economist', 'url': 'https://www.economist.com/britain/rss.xml'},
    {'name': 'Mother Jones', 'url': 'https://www.motherjones.com/politics/feed/'},
    {'name': 'The Young Turks', 'url': 'https://legacy.tyt.com/category/public/feed/?_gl=1%2A1q3bbpg%2A_gcl_au%2ANDIxNjk0NzgxLjE3MDIxMzY0MzU.'},
    {'name': 'Washington Post - Opinion', 'url': 'https://www.washingtonpost.com/arcio/rss/category/opinions/?itid=lk_inline_manual_7'},
    # Add more feeds as needed
]

def fetch_image_url(article_link):
    try:
        # Fetch the article webpage
        response = requests.get(article_link)
        response.raise_for_status()

        # Parse the webpage content to extract the image URL
        soup = BeautifulSoup(response.text, 'html.parser')
        image_tag = soup.find('meta', attrs={'property': 'og:image'}) or soup.find('meta', attrs={'name': 'og:image'})
        image_url = image_tag.get('content') if image_tag else None

        return image_url
    except Exception as e:
        print(f"Error fetching image for {article_link}: {e}")
        return None

@app.route('/')
def index():
    # Fetch and parse RSS feeds
    articles = []
    for feed in rss_feeds:
        feed_data = feedparser.parse(feed['url'])
        for entry in feed_data.entries:
            # Fetch image URL for each article
            image_url = fetch_image_url(entry.link)

            # Add image URL to the article entry
            entry.media_thumbnail = [{'url': image_url}] if image_url else []

            articles.append(entry)

    # Sort articles by published date (handle missing 'published_parsed' attribute)
    articles.sort(key=lambda x: x.get('published_parsed', (0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0)), reverse=True)

    return render_template('index.html', articles=articles)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(debug=True)
```

Comment: That is just a link to an image - https://i.stack.imgur.com/o1twU.png

Comment: That's what the website is currently displaying - nothing but the banner.

Comment: Oh I see.......

Comment: At what point is the problem? Retrieving, displaying, etc?

Comment: Also I've had problems with being blocked by cloudflare on PYthonAnywhere when using certain libraries (like urllib). Maybe have the rss feed be written to a file, and you can see if it is in the file - the problem is displaying it. If not, the problem is retrieving it.

Comment: Also maybe try some Python libraries that are meant for dealing with RSS feeds, instead of requests.

Comment: if you have a free account, then there is the restriction i.e -> restricted outbound Internet access from your apps.